# Jquery complete execution of animation even after timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

So I have the script that is executed on page load..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit").hide("slow");
        $("#logo").animate({
            left: '-115px',
            top: '-60%'
        });
        $("#logo-side").animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 3000);
        $("#wrapper").unwrap();
    }, 2000);
});
```

basically I want `#logo-side` to fade in **AFTER** the `setTimeout` and not sure how to script it.  Can someone help ?

Comment: The `#logo-side` will fade in after the timeout...? Do you mean that you want it to fade in after the `#logo` animation has completed?

Comment: yes basically , logo gets animated , loader wrapper fades , the logo-side fades in after these two

Comment: jquery animate has an optional complete param. Use it .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] ). http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: oh right just looking it up now , gotta make sure i get my syntax right :)

Comment: @SherinMathew any idea on how i integrate the complete to my function  ?

Comment: @havingagoatit Did you try modifying your code to pass in the complete method? If so, please show us the code. Something in jsfiddle will be useful. We should be able to resolve the issue faster.

Comment: @SherinMathew No I didn't manage to get a solution to this one and have left it for a later time as it appears the solution is not as simple as using complete apparently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no answer as to why it wouldnt fade in properly if something els happened but it is probably down to the initialisation of a multipushmenu that stops every function before it does its own stuff... crazy really but there we are !

Answer (score 2):

use animate callback function on `$("#logo")`.  read more about  [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     setTimeout(function() {
        $("#loader-wrapper .loader-section, #textbit").hide("slow");
        $("#logo").animate({
          left: '-115px',
          top: '-60%'
        },'slow',function(){
           $("#logo-side").animate({
           opacity: 1
           }, 3000);
       });

       $("#wrapper").unwrap();
    }, 2000);
 });
```

Comment: this doesn't allow the animation to complete

Comment: it is logo-side that i need to complete regardless of timer not logo in case this helps

Comment: @havingagoatit i have added duration to `$("#logo") ` . may be this will work for you :)

Comment: thanks for hlpeing but it is actually #logo-side that is being stopped before it completes